# Updating multiple excel sheets using Python

Tags: python, excel, jupyter-notebook

I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong. I'm using Jupyter notebooks to update 5 excel sheets at once after reading through the section in Automate the boring stuff with python. I want to basically add 5 rows at the top and include text on the first row, but so far I'm not even able to insert rows.

Here's what my code looks like so far:

```
import OS
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path=r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projects"
os.chdir(path)

for files in os.listdir(path):
     wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(files)
     sheet = wb['testing']
     sheet.insert_rows(idx=1, amount=5)
```

I checked the excel workbooks after and saw no change. Am I using Jupyter wrong? I do also have Sublime text editor but not sure how to load packages there. If there's any helpful links that any one has for iterating through excel files for a very very beginner level person, it would be helpful.

Comment: wb.save() is what you need to save your changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to call [`wb.save()`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.workbook.workbook.html?highlight=save#openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook.save) after modifying the sheet.

Comment: I get an error that says: TypeError: save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'

Comment: @zeeriaz Read the docs I linked to. Also, that error is self-explanatory... you need to provide a filename...

Comment: Omg sorry and thank you! I just realized to do wb.save(files) Thank you so much